# Changing multiple row colours in Report Builder

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I would like to change the row colours in the attached image so all rows match with the value in NAME column.[image]

So I want the related 2 rows in CUST CODE, DEL TO, CUST NAME and then the related 3 rows in ORDER NO to be the same colour.

Then i would like the colours to alternate for the next NAME value and so on.

Is this possible? I know how to alternate row colour when each result is one row only, but unsure how to do it with this kind of result.

So to clarify, for NAME (AHe) all rows to be 'lightgrey', NAME (AHO) all rows to be 'whitesmoke', NAME (JH) all rows to be 'lightgrey' etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used something similar to the following in the background color expression:

```
=IIF(RUNNINGVALUE(Fields!Name.Value, COUNTDISTINCT,"MainDataSet") MOD 2 = 0, 
       "LightGrey", 
        "WhiteSmoke")
```

There may be another way to do this using `ROWNUMBER()` or another alternative as well.

Comment: error message: 'The backgroundColor expression for the text box 'NAME' has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.

Comment: Did you put your main data set in the quotes?

Comment: thanks for highlighting my stupidity! sorted now, just what i wanted. Thanks. Can you explain what exactly that expression is doing? Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help. The expression is giving every distinct name a row number and using the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). If the row number divided by 2 has a remainder (odd numbers) then the color will be White Smoke.